# preg_replace_callback pattern not containing certain sub-string

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

Currently i am using the following code to modify content between `{|` and `|}` using a custom function `parse_table`

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("({\|(.*?)\|})is", function($m) {return parse_table($m[1]);}, $input);
```

Now i want to modify it such that the pattern can exclude a certain substring, such as `abcde`. What could be done to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in your regex:

```
"({\|(?!abcde)(.*?)\|})is"
```

However, this would get very difficult to read, very fast. Instead, use the callback:

```
function($m) {
    if( $m[1] == "abcde") return $m[0];
    return parse_table($m[1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm very week at regular expression. Your option to use it inside the callback is brilliant. Only one thing is you should change the conditional part to `if (strpos($m[1], 'abcde') !== false) . Thank you very much.